# Change varchar m/d/yy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: mysql, date

I have a varchar(9) column with data that is in the form m/d/yy.  I want to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd.  I can select all the values and view my changes using this query,

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_new,'%m/%d/%Y') as date
  FROM july
```

My problem is how to update all those values in that column.  I tried using this query, messes up all the dates.

```sql
UPDATE july
   SET date_new = str_to_date(date_new, '%d-%m-%Y' );
```

Any help would be gladly accepted!

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: I would also suggest changing the type of your column to `date` or equivalent. There's no good reason to store a date in a `varchar` field.

Comment: I don't plan on storing it in a varchar field.  I received a file that had all their values stored in varchar to begin with.  I have to convert them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. You can use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert it back to the desired string representation.

```sql
UPDATE july
   SET date_new = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_new,'%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

**Note:** You'd need to change your column from `varchar(9)` to `varchar(10)` to fit reformatted values.

```sql
ALTER TABLE july MODIFY date_new VARCHAR(10);
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de61cf/1).